# Connection Xiaomi MiBand 3 with Dart Language (Flutter) #689

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth, xiaomi

Good afternoon, I need to integrate the xiaomi smart bracelet (miband 3) in the Dart language (Flutter), but I am having difficulty, there is very little support material regarding this integration specifically.

I found only one repository on GitHub that makes this call, I was able to connect via bluetooth with the bracelet but I can't receive and send alert data for example. The services are listed, but when I click on read or write nothing happens. Can anyone help me with this?

I used the plugin flutter_blue and the code of the example is here: https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart